# -bash: SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am starting the spark python shell in cynwin , but it returns an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb90e.png). Could anyone advise what should I do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space between the dollar sign and the name of the variable.